# How do I use checkboxes to pass value to views django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to use checkboxes to get the selected options from the user and pass it onto the views to create a new instance using the value, however, I am finding it difficult to get the input value as it keeps showing None the I try getting the value using the input name within the tag.

template

```
                     <form action='/print_from_button' method='GET'>
                        <table id="id_list_table" class="table table-condensed">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th id="input">Input</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody id="fbody">
                              {%for m in matches%}
                                  <tr>
                                      <td><br>{{ m.match }}</br> ({{m.datespent}})</td>
                                      <td>
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="inputs" class="checkvalue" value={{m.match}} />
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                              {%endfor%}
                              </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <input type="text" name="checkval" id="checkallvalues" size="50">
                        <button type='submit'> Confirm </button>
                      </form>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import matchpaymentsoverview
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
   path('matchpayment/overview/',views.matchpaymentsoverview, name="matchpaymentsoverview"),
   path('print_from_button', views.print_from_button)    
]
```

views.py

```
def print_from_button(request):
   print("button clicked")
   if request.POST.get('checkval'):
      vi = request.POST.get('checkval')
      print(vi)
   vi1 = request.GET.get('checkval')
   print(vi1)
   list_of_input_ids=request.POST.getlist('inputs')
   print(list_of_input_ids)
   return HttpResponse("""<html><script>window.location.replace('/');</script></html>""")
```

I keep getting none when I print the above name tags, would I need the button to trigger the function, or I can just create a function and use the get to get the values. Hope it makes sense.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could you HTML Checkboxes like this:

```html
<p>Choose your monster's features:</p>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="scales" name="scales"
         checked>
  <label for="scales">Scales</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="horns" name="horns">
  <label for="horns">Horns</label>
</div>
```

Basically this is just a input field with the type **checkbox**. You also could use Django input fields:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/

This is the source of my code:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Mozialla is a good choice in general if you have any questions about html, javascript or css